# How to set dynamic panel as component's parent?

Tags: delphi, vcl

well, I am creating at runtime a TImage and a Tlabel, I want those two to be child of a Tpanel, which I also create at runtime.
here is some code:

```
with TPanel.Create(FlowPanelPlantillas) do
begin
  Name := 'Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
  //Etc Etc
end;
```

and the image

```
with TImage.Create(TWinControl(FindComponent('Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString))) do
  begin
    Name:= 'P'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
    Parent := TWinControl(FindComponent('Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString));        
  end;
```

that is what I am doing but I doesn’t work, the panel is created and viewed properly but the image doesn’t appear in the panel, it is empty.

I am using Delphi Rio VCL

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use a variable when you are creating the panel and set the image parent to this variable

Comment: Avoid using `with`. It has potential to give you some serious headaches in the future because of the implicit scope involved.

Comment: your Advice supports Remy's answer, I will change my code in order to avoid using "With".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `with` statement does not provide you access to the object that is being referenced.  You need that reference in order to assign it to something, like a `Parent` property.  You should save the reference to a variable first.

Also, don't forget to set the `Visible` property, too.

Try this:

```
var
  Panel: TPanel;

Panel := TPanel.Create(FlowPanelPlantillas);
with Panel do
begin
  Name := 'Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
  //Etc Etcl
  Visible := True;
end;

...

Panel := TWinControl(FindComponent('Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString));
// or, just use the same variable already assigned
// previously, if it is still in scope...

with TImage.Create(Panel) do
begin
  Name:= 'P'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
  Parent := Panel;
  Visible := True;
end;
```

There is really very little use for `FindComponent()` and named objects in properly designed dynamic code.  The naming system is *primarily* meant for DFM streaming only.

For that matter, once you have a variable with an object reference in it, there is very little use for `with`, either:

```
var
  Panel: TPanel;
  Image: TImage;

Panel := TPanel.Create(FlowPanelPlantillas);
Panel.Name := 'Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
//Etc Etcl
Panel.Visible := True;

...

Panel := TWinControl(FindComponent('Panel'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString));
// or, just use the same variable already assigned
// previously, if it is still in scope...

Image := TImage.Create(Panel);
Image.Name := 'P'+Query.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
Image.Parent := Panel;
Image.Visible := True;
```

Using variables to hold the object references also helps with debugging, so you can make sure your variables are actually receiving the values you are expecting.  You don't get that option when using `with`.

Comment: it Helped me a lot and thanks for explaining it on detail about using "with" so as to avoid spending too much time debugging.